# Exam-project: Is there any way for a newbie to create a onepage scroll-nav without JS?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm currently struggling with a project for my exam. We've learned a bit HTML and CSS but not any JS yet.
In this project I have to code my entire portfolio-website from scratch, and I'm not allowed to use Bootstrap or any kinds of templates and pre-made stuff. I really want to make a onepage navigation bar that scrolls down to a certain point at my page - but it looks like it's not possible to make it without JS. If anyone can enlighten me, please do. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes below will work for you.

HTML

```
<div class="button-groub">
  <a href="#1">1</a>
  <a href="#2">2</a>
  <a href="#3">3</a>
  <a href="#4">4</a>
</div>
<section id="1" class="section1">1</section>
<section id="2" class="section2">2</section>
<section id="3" class="section3">3</section>
<section id="4" class="section4">4</section>
```

CSS

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.button-groub{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20vh;
  right: 10vh;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
}
.button-groub > a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: black;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;

}
.section1 {
  background-color: #34495e;
}
.section2 {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}
.section3 {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.section4 {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me a lot!